# почему дает ошибку на v-for

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Form inputs</h2>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="instagram"  v-model="social"> Instagram
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Vk" v-model="social"> Vk
    </label>

    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Facebook"  v-model="social"> Facebook
    </label>

    <hr>

    <ul>
    <li v-for="s in social"> {{ s }} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      social:[]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Не удалось скомпилировать. 

./src/App.vue
Ошибка модуля (из ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C: \ Users \ User \ Documents \ веб-проекта \ SRC \ App.vue 
19: 5 ошибок   Элементы итерации ожидают иметь 'v-обязывать: ключ' директивы   вю / требуют-v-для-ключ  ​  

✖ 1 проблема (1 ошибка, 0 предупреждений)

Comment: дополните этим, пожалуйста, сам текст вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вы не читаете ошибок? `:key` необходимо указать.

Comment: но я не знаю как это.    привидете пожалуйста пример

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [документацию](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-v-for), там есть пример цикла с ключем, в вашем случае это будет так:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="s in social" :key="social"> {{ s }} </li>
</ul>
```

Я так понял больше для ключа нечего дать вам, или попробуйте вариант:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(s, index) in social"> {{ s }} </li>
</ul>
```

Но не уверен что сработает, первый вариант точно рабочий.

Comment: Спасибо       вот так зделал работет уже    li v-for="s in social" :key="s"> {{ s }} </li>